# How to configure FuncAnimation (dynamic plotting from matplotlib.animation) to numpy arrays?

Tags: python, dynamic, matplotlib, pde

I have some issues with the *FuncAnimation* fonction of *MatPlotLib*.  I can't configure it to my code... I hope someone could help me !!

This is a diffusion equation, I need to plot it for each step of the time. At each step, the result of the calculation is a numpy array. I manage to plot it in a dynamic way with *pyplot.interactive(True)* but it is very laggy. I read that *FuncAnimation* can deal with that problem but I did not manage to have it working with results in lists or arrays.

Here is the code with a classic slow plot :
It produces a vector of vectors (*U*) wich are ploted after all calculations

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.linalg import solve_banded
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def DrawRecord(U):
    plt.interactive(True)
    plt.figure(1)
    for i in range(0,len(U)):
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(U[i])
        plt.ylim([0,1])
        plt.draw()

J=350.0 
dt=0.01 
T=3.0 
t=np.arange(dt,T,dt) 
dx=1.0/J 

D=0.005 
c=0.5 
r=0.1 

mu=c*dt/(2.0*dx) 
lambd=D*dt/(dx**2.0) 

K_x=50.0*np.ones(J-1) 
alpha_t=0.5*np.ones(len(t)) 

#initial conditions
u=np.zeros(J) 
u[J/5*1:J/5*2]=1 
U=u

espace=np.linspace(0,1,J) 

#Matrix
A=np.diag(-lambd*np.ones(J-2),1)+np.diag((1+2*lambd)*np.ones(J-1),0)+np.diag(-lambd*np.ones(J-2),-1)  
AA=scipy.linalg.inv(A)


for i in t:

    u[1:J]=scipy.dot(AA,u[1:J]+(r-alpha_t[i/dt])*dt*(u[1:J]-u[1:J]/K_x))
    u[0]=0 
    u[J-1]=0  

    U=np.vstack([U,u])

DrawRecord(U)
```

And here is my try of making turn the *FuncAnimation* with the previous code (big fail) :
*nb :* U contents the arrays of results calculated for each steps

```
global U

fig = plt.figure()
window = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = window.plot(list(U[1,:]))

def init():
    line=list(U[1,:])
    return line

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(list(U[i,:]))
    return line

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

That produces a lot of errors ... Maybe someone can set it up for the previous code !
I hope I'm clear (sorry for my english) and thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init function isn't right, it should be:

```
def init():
    line.set_ydata(U[1,:])
    return line
```

You also don't need to convert the numpy slice to a list.

Comment: Indeed this seems better but I still have it crashing :     
TypeError: 'Line2D' object is not iterable  


    global U

    fig = plt.figure()
    window = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = window.plot(U[1,:]))

    def init():
        line.set_ydata(U[1,:])
        return line

    def animate(i):
     line.set_ydata(U[i,:])
     return line

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

    plt.show()


Any ideas ??

Comment: clear version :
 
Indeed this seems better but I still have it crashing : *TypeError: 'Line2D' object is not iterable*

 Any ideas ?? thanks

Comment: @kadok What version of matplotlib are you using? Can you figure out where in your code the error is coming from (I suspect line 4)?  A dead simple de-bugging tactic is to add `print` statements and see which ones get printed before the exception.  The error is telling  you that you are trying to iterate over a `Line2D` object (which is not an iterable object so a type error is thrown).

Answer (score 2):

FuncAnimation expects an iterable to return from init and update

try this:

```
def init():
    line.set_ydata(U[1,:])
    return line,
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error, and I fixed it by adding a comma.

```
def init():
    line.set_ydata(U[1,:])
    return line,
```

For some reason this fixed it.  You don't need the trailing comma if you have more than one object you're returning.  Bloody cryptic error message, if you ask me.